# Is there a way to add multiple columns (and edit the values) based on another multiple conditions on another column?

Tags: r

I am working on a dataset of compilation of vaccination records of different countries. I would like to add multiple columns of different vaccines used by the countries by indicating 1 or 0.

[Preview of "vaccines" column of dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUDxQ.png)

```
list_4 
OUTPUT
[1] "Pfizer/BioNTech"    "Sputnik V"          "Oxford/AstraZeneca" "Moderna"            "Sinopharm/Beijing"  "Sinovac"            "Sinopharm/Wuhan"   
 [8] "Covaxin"            "EpiVacCorona"       "Johnson&Johnson"   
[1] "character"
```

I was able to achieve ([Final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJJZt.png)) it with the code below (hard coding), is there any way to achieve the same result by utilising list_4 directly?

```
data_6 <- data_5 %>% 
  mutate("Pfizer/BioNTech" = ifelse(str_detect(vaccines, "Pfizer/BioNTech"), 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate("Sputnik V" = ifelse(str_detect(vaccines, "Sputnik V"), 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate("Oxford/AstraZeneca" = ifelse(str_detect(vaccines, "Oxford/AstraZeneca"), 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate("Moderna" = ifelse(str_detect(vaccines, "Moderna"), 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate("Sinopharm/Beijing" = ifelse(str_detect(vaccines, "Sinopharm/Beijing"), 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate("Sinovac" = ifelse(str_detect(vaccines, "Sinovac"), 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate("Sinopharm/Wuhan" = ifelse(str_detect(vaccines, "Sinopharm/Wuhan"), 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate("Covaxin" = ifelse(str_detect(vaccines, "Covaxin"), 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate("EpiVacCorona" = ifelse(str_detect(vaccines, "EpiVacCorona"), 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate("Johnson&Johnson" = ifelse(str_detect(vaccines, "Johnson&Johnson"), 1, 0))
```

Comment: Please share the actual dataset as code, not images. You can use `dput(data_5)`. Please share a subset that includes this  `list_4` column

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the OP is looking for a way to get dummy cols that tell whether a given vaccine is present in the vector of vaccines contained in every row.

**small reprex**

```
strings <- c('Oxford/AstraZeneca, Sputnik V', 'Moderna, Oxford/AstraZeneca')
vaccines <- c('Oxford/AstraZeneca', 'Sputnik V', 'Moderna')
df <- tibble(strings)

df

# A tibble: 2 × 1
  strings                      
  <chr>                        
1 Oxford/AstraZeneca, Sputnik V
2 Moderna, Oxford/AstraZeneca
```

**answer**

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
        mutate(map_dfc(vaccines, ~+str_detect(strings, .x)) %>%
                       set_names(vaccines))

# A tibble: 2 × 4
  strings                       `Oxford/AstraZeneca` `Sputnik V` Moderna
  <chr>                                        <int>       <int>   <int>
1 Oxford/AstraZeneca, Sputnik V                    1           1       0
2 Moderna, Oxford/AstraZeneca                      1           0       1
```